# Populate issue with mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to populate all the stories that are stored in the stories array with a reference to the story id like this but I do not get back any stories when I know they are there... and for some reason I get the stories of another user in my db does that make sense...

here is how I reference it in my mongoose schema:

```
stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }],
```

This is the populate query that does not return the correct results:

```
User.find({_id: query}).populate({
                path: "stories",
                select: "_id name location date_updated date_created picture",
                options: {limit: limit, skip: skipCount }
        }).exec(function(err, users) {
                if(err) console.log(err);
                console.log(users);
                res.json(users);
        });
```

query is the userId being passed back and limit and skipCount are being set accordingly (skip is 0, limit is 100. I am trying to get back all the stories that are in the user's stories array...